# Does HTTP/2's opportunistic encryption potentially allow man-in-the-middle attacks?

Tags: tls, man-in-the-middle

HTTP/2's opportunistic encryption of http URIs using TLS appears to allow the possibility of man-in-the-middle attacks. Is that true?

[RFC for opportunistic encryption](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7435).

[Here's HTTP/2's spec for opportunistic encryption](https://httpwg.github.io/http-extensions/encryption.html#goals-and-non-goals).

Answer (score 6):

Opportunistic encryption assumes only a passive attacker (i.e. sniffing only) and thus of course makes man-in-the-middle attacks by an active attacker (which can modify the connection) possible. This is not restricted to HTTP/2 but a general limitation of opportunistic encryption. See also [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opportunistic_encryption) about this topic.